# Is it possible for a cxx_library to export preprocessor macros?

Tags: c++, buck

I am using [buck](/questions/tagged/buck) to build some C++ code. I have a library (not my own!) that sets some preprocessor macro that are required by another library (not my own!).

Does Buck provide a way for modules to export preprocessor macros?

For example, library `A` contains a header file that sets `MY_MACRO`; library `B` depends on library `A` and has some code that requires `MY_MACRO` to be set.

Comment: Files from Library B that need the macro should include an appropriate header file from Library A.

Answer (score 1):

With your [`cxx_library`](https://buckbuild.com/rule/cxx_library.html), add an `exported_headers` containing the `.h` files that contain your macros.  This will then be made available to dependent libraries.